# How to remove Rho labels from Matlab polar plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In my polar plot in Matlab, I have default labels for Theta (0, 30, 60, .., 330) and Rho (20, 40, .., 100).
I can remove Theta label using command

```
set(findall(gca, 'String', '0'),'String', ' ');
```

Please advice how to remove Rho labels (20, 40, .., 100) from the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all labels simply type

```
delete(findall(gcf,'type','text'));
```

Since the polar plot labels are hidden text objects placed around on the plot, you can not simply find them by accessing axes. To remove only some of them you will need to explicitly find the text objects containing those particular labels you want to delete. In your case, look for text objects containing Rho:

```
% Get all strings in the hidden labels, choose the ones you want to delete
% Note that some of the labels may contain spaces - you need to be exact.
get(findall(gcf, 'type', 'text'), 'string');

% say your labels have the following strings..
rho_labels = {'20' '40' '60' '80' '100'};
for r=1:length(rho_labels)
    delete(findall(gcf, 'string', rho_labels{r}))
end
```

Comment: This command deletes all labels from the figure which is not needed. I'm trying to remove only Rho labels.

Comment: @Dmitry which labels do you want to remove? Your command only removes the Theta=0 label. You have to be more specific then.

Comment: You're right my command removes only Theta=0 label. It was given for example. I want to remove all **rho** lables (20, 40, .., 100).

Comment: In my case, I had to put 2 spaces before numbers. I've corrected your answer accordingly.