# how to remove argument labels from polar plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know a simple way to remove the labels from the argument axis in a polar plot in MATLAB? My figures are small and I have to zoom in to see them, but when I do this the argument labels from one subplot get in the way of the other subplots.

Equally, if anyone knows of a way to solve this issue by rescaling the axis in the radial direction, or of any solution for that matter, then I would be very grateful. For the mean time I'll have to trim and re-size in Latex.

---

I tried the method here

[How to remove Rho labels from Matlab polar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581008/how-to-remove-rho-labels-from-matlab-polar-plot)

but it didn't work.

---

here is some sample code

```
    subplot(1,3,1,'align');
    r = 10;
       polar(t,abs((r.*exp(t.*1i) - (1+1i)).^2));

      set(gca, 'fontsize', 20)
     set(findall(gca, 'String', '0'),'String', ' ') %remove theta labels
     hold on
```

Comment: PLease, provide some sample code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `set(findall(gca, 'type', 'text'),'string','')`

Comment: and that wont kill all of the radius labels too?

Answer (score 4):

Given the following example input:

```
t = 0:.01:2*pi;
polar(t,sin(2*t).*cos(2*t),'--r')
```

[image]

You can remove the vertical labels (along rho) by keeping only the legit ones.

```
% Find all handles to text labels
h     = findall(gca,'type','text');

% Define what to keep
legit = {'0','30','60','90','120','150','180','210','240','270','300','330','360',''};

% Take the others and set them to empty string
idx   = ~ismember(get(h,'string'),legit);
set(h(idx),'string','')
```

**EDIT** addressing comments

One approach would be simply setting to empty string `''` those labels defined IN `legit`, i.e. by removing `~` near `ismember`. However, this approach is not robust in the sense that it will remove all of the labels that match. Suppose you have some other label with `120`, then it will be removed as well.

One way to solve this issue is to edit `polar()` on line 155 and 162 by adding a `'Tag'` to the radial annotations:

```
'HandleVisibility', 'off', 'Parent', cax,'Tag','spoke');
```

Then, save the edited function, plot, retrieve those text labels, and set to empty string:

```
h = findall(gca,'Type','text','-and','Tag','spoke');
set(h,'string','')
```

Comment: thank you, this is useful. My question is asking how to remove the theta labels, though --  I apologise for my unclear use of the word argument. Do you know how this is done? a similar method I guess...